# Does the Community♦ user auto correct answers and add links?

Tags: discussion

or is it done manually?

I've [noticed an answer on](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3426/can-you-remember-specific-things-you-learn-in-the-womb/4482#4482) one of my earlier posts which missed references has properly been updated with reference links by the Community♦

Is this an intelligent bot searching Google for matches or some good soul cleaning up answers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is an edit by an anonymous user. Anonymous users can suggest edits to older posts, but those edits have to be approved by a high-rep user. Those edits show up as edits from the community user.